# ReactJS: the value in the input doesn't change when the state is update

Tags: reactjs, input, state

I try to implement a list of crop, and the user can modify the surface, the yield and the price of each crop. My initial state as a surface of 0, and a yield and a price that's been already define, the initial state look like that

```
C1 : ['Blé tendre', 0, 8.3, 191]
C2 : ["Orge d'hivers et escourgeon", 0, 6.75, 181]
C3 : ['Maïs grain', 0, 9.99, 178]
C4 : ['Soja', 0, 2.73, 379]
```

When the user types in the input of the surface, it is supposed to update the surface of the crop in the state and it did because the `console.log` of the state shows me this when I type 20 in the input of 'Blé tendre':

```
C1 : ['Blé tendre', 20, 8.3, 191]
C2 : ["Orge d'hivers et escourgeon", 0, 6.75, 181]
C3 : ['Maïs grain', 0, 9.99, 178]
C4 : ['Soja', 0, 2.73, 379]
```

I have the main file with the state in it:

Assolement.js

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';
import {Navigate} from 'react-router-dom'
import Entete from '../MEP/entete'
import Culture from './culture_assol'

function Assolement() {
  const [goToExploit, setGoToExploit] = useState(false)
  const [data, setData] = useState({"C1": ["Blé tendre", 0,8.3, 191], "C2": ["Orge d'hivers et escourgeon",0, 6.75, 181], "C3" :["Maïs grain",0, 9.99, 178], "C4": ["Soja",0, 2.73, 379]})

  const table_assol=  Object.keys(data).map(key => (
    <Culture 
    keys={key}
    data={data}
    MAJ_surf={MAJ_surf}
    libelle={data[key][0]}
    />
  ))

  function MAJ_surf(key,surf) {
    var newData= data;
    newData[key][1] = parseFloat(surf)//execute the manipulations
    setData(newData)
    setData(prev => {
      return prev;
    })
    console.log('surf')
    console.log(surf)
    console.log('data')
    console.log(data)
    console.log(data[key][1])    
  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    setGoToExploit(true)
  }

  if(goToExploit) {
    return <Navigate push to={`/exploitation`}/>
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Entete titre="Assolement"/>
      <div className='container'>
        <h1>  </h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className='table_assol'>
            {table_assol}
          </div>
          <div className='row'>
            <button type='submit' className='validation'> Enregistrer </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Assolement;
```

And I have a culture_assol.js file that contains each crop (because at the end the list of crop is not gooing to be static and can move between 2 to 52 crops)

culture_assol.js

```
import React from 'react'

const Culture = ({keys,data, MAJ_surf, libelle}) => {
    function handleChangeSurface(event) {
        var surf = event.target.value;
        MAJ_surf(keys, surf);
        console.log(data)
        console.log(data[keys])
        console.log(data[keys][1])
    }

    return (
        <div className='row ligne_assol'>
            <div className='col_assol col_libelle'>
            {libelle}
            </div>
            <div className='col_assol col_surface'>
            <div className='videBlocAssol'>
                <input 
                className='input_assol'
                onChange={handleChangeSurface}
                value= {data[keys][1]}
                placeholder='0'
                type='text'/>
                <div className='pleinBlocAssol'>
                ha
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div className='col_assol col_rdt'>
            <div className='videBlocAssol'>
            <input 
                className='input_assol'
                value= {data[keys][2]}
                type='text'/>
                <div className='pleinBlocAssol'>
                t/ha
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div className='col_assol col_prix'>
            <div className='videBlocAssol'>
                <input 
                className='input_assol'
                value= {data[keys][3]}
                type='text'/>
                <div className='pleinBlocAssol'>
                €/t
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div className='col_assol col_PB_unitaire'>
            {Math.round(data[keys][2]*data[keys][3])} €
            </div>
            <div className='col_assol col_PB_tit_Prod'>
            {Math.round(data[keys][1]*data[keys][2]*data[keys][3])} €
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Culture;
```

Here is my code in a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/value-in-the-input-doesnt-change-when-the-state-is-updatel-owo9sl)

I tried :

- put the Maj_surf in the componen culure_assol,
- without the setData(newData) setData(prev => {return prev;}) just with setData

Please if someone can help me or guide me to solve the problem

Comment: can you create a sandbox?

Comment: Yes I do that right now

Comment: I edit my post and add the SandBox @Apostolos

Comment: ok this is better. see my answer

Comment: Sorry but I can't see your answer in the sandbox @Apostolos

Comment: i have added a link to my sandbox in my answer, though it is just one line change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are mutating the state which leads to no updates at all.

The problematic part is this

```
  function MAJ_surf(key, surf) {
    var newData = data;
```

You need to create a new object like this

```
  function MAJ_surf(key, surf) {
    var newData = {...data};
```

[fixed sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/value-in-the-input-doesnt-change-when-the-state-is-updatel-owo9sl?file=/src/App.js:513-715)

Comment: Ok I understand the problem now, thanks a lot, have a nice day